# Add additional column in a SELECT statement based on values of other columns PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, aggregate-functions, psql

I have a table of driver licenses per person and know when a person acquired the drivers license. The validity of the drivers license can either be X days from the day you acquired it or a specific date.

```
 acquired        relative      specific_date      valid_type     expiration_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-02-05         500             null              days
2015-02-05         null         2016-03-05           date
2015-02-05         200             null              days
2015-02-05         null         2016-02-22           date
```

My query right now would be:

```
SELECT acquired,
       relative_date,
       specific_date,
       valid_type
FROM person_drivers_license
WHERE (valid_type = 'days'
       AND (EXTRACT(epoch
                    FROM acquired) - EXTRACT(epoch
                                             FROM now()))/86400 + relative_date > 0)
  OR (valid_type = 'DATE'
      AND specific_date >= now()));
```

I am trying to add an expiration_date column with the select statement above. If it is a specific date, just take the date and put it in expiration_date and if it is a relative date, calculate the expiration date with the help of the acquired date. Is this possible in PSQL?

Comment: Check `COALESCE()` function. Or a more complex `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE END`

Comment: Whats the output supposed to be?

Comment: It' supposed to be that table that I have written with the expiration_date column populated with the date of when the licsense expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - there is a simpler way to do date math in postgres. You can use something like:

```
acquired + relative_date * interval '1 day' >= current_date
```

or

```
acquired + relative_date >= current_date 
-- any integer can be treated as interval in days for date mathematics is SQL
```

For the question - try one of this:

```
CASE WHEN valid_type = 'days' 
     THEN acquired + relative_date * interval '1 day'
     WHEN valid_type = 'date'
     THEN specific_date
     --ELSE ??? you may specify something here
END
```

or

```
COALESCE(specific_date, acquired + relative_date * interval '1 day')
```

The query may look like:

```
SELECT acquired,
       relative_date,
       specific_date,
       valid_type,
       COALESCE(specific_date, acquired + relative_date * interval '1 day') as valid_date
FROM person_drivers_license
WHERE COALESCE(specific_date, acquired + relative_date * interval '1 day') >= current_date
```

Comment: Thank you! This works except for one small thing. I'm getting the time too and not just the date in my new column. Probably because my acquired column has timestamp.

Comment: @uraza This means that one of the inputs is `timestamp`, not an actual date. You can `cast(... as date)` to truncate a `timestamp` to a `date`. BTW `now()` returns `timestamp`. `current_date` returns `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT acquired,
       relative_date,
       specific_date,
       valid_type
       CASE valid_type
         WHEN 'days' THEN acquired + relative_date
         WHEN 'date' THEN specific_date
         ELSE NULL
       END AS expiration_date
FROM   person_drivers_license;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pl/sql

```
SELECT acquired,
       relative_date,
       specific_date,
       valid_type,
       CASE WHEN specific date = "date" -- starts here
       THEN specific date 
       ELSE acquired + cast('1 months' as interval)END 
       AS expiration_date -- end here
FROM person_drivers_license
WHERE (valid_type = 'days'
       AND (EXTRACT(epoch
                    FROM acquired) - EXTRACT(epoch
                                             FROM now()))/86400 + relative_date > 0)
  OR (valid_type = 'DATE'
      AND specific_date >= now()));
```

Comment: Postgres does not have `DateAdd()` function. Please read postgres manual for examples of date math: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Indeed @IgorRomanchenko. Answer amended. Thanks for making me notice it.